# How to navigate through pagination? (Selenium)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to extract all the information by navigating through pagination.

The source code of pagination part is :

```
<tr class="pagination" valign="middle" align="center">
   <td colspan="9">
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td><span>1</span></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$2')">2</a></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$3')">3</a></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$4')">4</a></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$5')">5</a></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$6')">6</a></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$7')">7</a></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$8')">8</a></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$9')">9</a></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$10')">10</a></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$11')">...</a></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$Last')">Last</a></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

And my selenium script is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from datetime import date,timedelta
import sqlite3
import os

today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=2)
d3 = yesterday.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")

URL = 'https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil//rfq/rfqdates.aspx?category=recent'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

driver.get(URL)
driver.find_element_by_id("butAgree").click()
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(d3).click()
col1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[1]')
col2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[2]')
col3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[3]')
col4 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[4]')
col5 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[5]')
col6 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[6]')
col7 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[7]')
col8 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[8]')
col9 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[9]')

col1_data = [s.text for s in col1]
col2_data = [s.text for s in col2]
col3_data = [s.text for s in col3]
col4_data = [s.text for s in col4]
col5_data = [s.text for s in col5]
col6_data = [s.text for s in col6]
col7_data = [s.text for s in col7]
col8_data = [s.text for s in col8]
col9_data = [s.text for s in col9]
```

This code extracts data from one page, I want to extract from all the pages that are listed in the pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the code inside a while loop, with a variable `pagination_starting_point` and initial value could be set as 2, and for each iteration we will increase the counter.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

while True:
    try:
        col1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[1]')
        col2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[2]')
        col3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[3]')
        col4 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[4]')
        col5 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[5]')
        col6 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[6]')
        col7 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[7]')
        col8 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[8]')
        col9 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[9]')

        col1_data = [s.text for s in col1]
        col2_data = [s.text for s in col2]
        col3_data = [s.text for s in col3]
        col4_data = [s.text for s in col4]
        col5_data = [s.text for s in col5]
        col6_data = [s.text for s in col6]
        col7_data = [s.text for s in col7]
        col8_data = [s.text for s in col8]
        col9_data = [s.text for s in col9]

        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//a[contains(@href,'Page${pagination_starting_point}')]"))).click()
        print("Click on page " + pagination_starting_point)
        pagination_starting_point = pagination_starting_point + 1
        if pagination_starting_point == 45:
            break
    except:
        print("Looks like job done !")
        break
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Updated to use xpath `//a[contains(@href,'Page${pagination_starting_point}')]` instead of page number.

Comment: Updated to use xpath `//a[contains(@href,'Page${pagination_starting_point}')]` instead of page number. You should put a break from while loop as well.

Comment: Selenium is second slowest way to do a manual scrapping. if you are looking to get only data, try request module.

Comment: I really can not help you. You mentioned selenium, and that's the only way in Selenium I know of.

Comment: Is there any way to find out the total number of pages i.e  `if pagination_starting_point == 45:` , this line will produce an exception when the number of pages is less?

Comment: Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't organize your code like that, avoid repetition using a function or list comprehensions:

```
all_cols = [driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f'//table[@id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch"]/tbody/tr/td[{i}]') for i in range(1,10)]
all_cols_data = [[s.text for s in col] for col in all_cols]
```

now you can access your data by indexing

Comment: the question is about pagination, not lists